# f-Strings in Sublime Text

Tags: python, macos, syntax-error, sublimetext3

If I check the version of Python my Terminal says its 3.8.1. But if I try using these f strings in Sublime Text I always get a syntax error.

Can anyone tell me why?

So here is my version, related to my terminal

```
Python 3.8.1 (v3.8.1:1b293b6006, Dec 18 2019, 14:08:53) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

This is the code:

```
greeting = 'Hello'
name = 'Hannah'

message = f'{greeting}, {name}. Welcome!'

print(message)
```

and this is the error:

```
File "/Users/bennimueller/Desktop/Intro.py", line 4
    message = f'{greeting}, {name}. Welcome!'
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/bennimueller/Desktop/Intro.py"]
[dir: /Users/bennimueller/Desktop]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: what does `which python` return?

Comment: Check what Python version is running the script: `import sys; print(sys.version)`. Also the error message should show the line where the error is occurring, no? If yes, please [edit] it into the question. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you very much! You're right, the error message shows where the error is occurring. And the return of `import sys; print(sys.version)` is `2.7.16 (default, Dec 13 2019, 18:00:32)`. 
Got it! Changed the build system to Python3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install Python from the python.org installer on macOS, the executable is actually called by running `python3`. Your [build system](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html) is actually calling `/usr/bin/python`, the version of Python 2 that comes with macOS.

To get around this, you just create a custom build system. Go to **`Tools`** → **`Build System`** → **`New Build System…`** (all the way at the bottom) and enter the contents below (delete all the placeholder template that comes up).

```
{
    "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

When you go to save the file, it will automatically put you in the proper directory -- it's `/Users/YourUserName/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User` if you're interested. Name the file `Python 3.sublime-build`, and there will now be a **`Tools`** → **`Build System`** → **`Python 3`** option.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.9 its :

**1.** Go to Sublime Text to: Tools -> Build System -> New Build System and put the next lines:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Then save it with a meaningful name like: `python3.sublime-build`

**2.** Go to Tools -> Build system -> and check python3

Test it with:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Press: Ctrl + b